# Getting the ACLs for another user than the current logged one in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, acl, symfony-2.1

I'm building a web application using Symfony2. I've been implementing the ACL modules and it worked perfectly, but stumbled on an issue when trying to make a pannel to manage rights.

So I got as user which can create a project and add "participants" on his project. The participants can have three different access type which are masks from the mask builder `MASK_VIEW`, `MASK_EDIT`, `MASK_OPERATOR`. Using the `ProblematicAclManagerBundle` we can easily add access to these using doing this :

```
$this->aclManager->addObjectPermission($project, $mask, $user);
```

The thing is that when you want to edit the project, you have to be able to list the users with their current access rights. The function `isGranted` can get you the users right for the current logged in user, but not for other users. Compared to the `addXXXX` functions where there are three arguments, the **`isGranted`** only have two, the secured object and the mask. Thus you cannot find the right for another user with this function.

---

Is there some sort of way to get the rights of other user built-in? Or do I have to build my own SQL queries to extract the data from the acl tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have right now... I made a raw sql query with nested selects.

```
//...
$objectClass = get_class($object);
$objectId = $object->getId();
$userSecurityIdentity = get_class($user) . '-' . $user->getUsername();

$sql = "SELECT `mask` FROM `acl_entries`" .
        "WHERE `object_identity_id` in (" .
            "SELECT `id` FROM `acl_object_identities` " .
            "WHERE `object_identifier` = :objectId AND `class_id` in (" .
                "SELECT `id` FROM `acl_classes` WHERE `class_type` = :objectClass" .
            ")" .
        ")" .
        "AND `security_identity_id` in (" .
            "SELECT `id` FROM `acl_security_identities`" .
            "WHERE `identifier` = :userSecurityIdentity" .
        ");";

$query = $this->entityManager->getConnection()->executeQuery($sql, array(
    'objectId'             => $objectId,
    'objectClass'          => $objectClass,
    'userSecurityIdentity' => $userSecurityIdentity)
);

$data = $query->fetch();
$mask = $data['mask'];
// ...
```

This solutions works, but is not the best one to me since you actually query directly the table instead of using the ACL module, I'll update if I find something else.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to put another token in the security context, linked to another user:

```
$securityContext->setToken(new Token($user2));
$securityContext->isGranted('test', $object);
```

Comment: Thing with that is that I would have to create a new Token that extends TokenInterface. Then mock the user as authenticated. It's a bit hacky but would work

Answer (score 0):

well the `Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Model\AclInterface` provides this method:

```
/**
 * Determines whether access is granted
 *
 * @throws NoAceFoundException when no ACE was applicable for this request
 * @param array   $masks
 * @param array   $securityIdentities
 * @param Boolean $administrativeMode
 * @return Boolean
 */
public function isGranted(array $masks, array $securityIdentities, $administrativeMode = false);
```

Comment: Thing is where would you put the object. When you insert a row you do `($mask, $object, $user)`. This doesn't seem to provide an argument for whether `$object` or `$user`.

Comment: It seems to check if the `identity` has the `mask` in any implemented object/class